# using $wpdb to get custom post type with term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wpdb, terms

I'm trying to get the title of the first custom post type with a specific term in a taxonomy.
But I'm not great at SQL so therefor not great with using `$wpdb`.

Here is my code:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ID, post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    WHERE post_type = 'property'
    AND $wpdb->terms.name = 'Locked'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'status'
");
echo $posts[0]->post_title;
```

Any suggestions on how to get the title of the first custom post type of 'property' with the term 'Locked' in the taxonomy 'status'?

**Update**
This is how I attempted this using `WP_Query`:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term
        ))
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        $loop->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

where `$term` is `"Locked"`.

What I really need is a way that I can query by multiple terms and taxonomies in an array or multiple arrays.
Any hints?

Comment: Why do you need SQL?  Why can't you use WP_Query with taxonomy parameters?

Comment: So I had looked at using WP_Query and here is the code that I used:

Comment: I had looked at using WP_Query and here is the code that I used:`<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'property', 'tax_query' => array(array(
'taxonomy' => 'Status',
'field'    => 'slug',        'terms'    => $term
 )));
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
the_title();
echo '<div class="entry-content">';
echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
the_content();
echo '</div>';
endwhile;?>`where $term is "Locked". What I really need is a way that I can query by multiple terms and taxonomies in an array or multiple arrays. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I'm not sure if that was best in a comment form or if there is a better way to reply with code.

Comment: You can edit your question (link on the bottom left). I took the liberty of doing that for you in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how to get the title of the first custom post type of 'property' with the term 'Locked' in the taxonomy 'status'?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'locked'
        )
    )
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) {
    $your_query->the_post();
    $the_title = get_the_title(); // variable $the_title now holds your title
}
```

> What I really need is a way that I can query by multiple terms and taxonomies.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'locked'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'color',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'blue'
        )
    )
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Related Reading:**
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters